# Declarative sentence and interrogative sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

> I said that Logics and English are inseparable.

That can be interpreted as I said, “Logics and English are inseparable.”

> I said why Logics and English are inseparable.

That may be interpreted in two ways.

1. I said, “Why are Logics and English inseparable?”
2. I said, “Logics and English are inseparable because…”

I can’t understand why sentence 2 makes sense even though ‘why Logics and English are inseparable’ is definitely an indirect **question**. Should it be changed into ‘I said about the reason why Logics and English are inseparable’?

Comment: ***to say*** is a poor verb to use in your example *I said why Logic and English are inseparable* - which can ***only*** carry your sense #2 *I **explained** why Logic and English are inseparable*, so you should use a verb like that rather than ***I said***. It's not a very good choice for your sense #1 either (that's better expressed by *I **asked** why Logic and English are inseparable*).

Comment: "Don’t tell me why I’m here" is a rather odd thing to say, but it can only really mean "I don't want you to tell me the reason why I am here. Presumably because the speaker himself knows perfectly well why he is wherever he is, and either he doesn't want to be *reminded* of that reason, OR he thinks the addressee is likely to suggest some *different* reason that's not true anyway.

Comment: Note that "why you are here" isn't a question. It's not even a *sentence*. It's just a ***noun phrase*** (equivalent to ***the reason for you being here***) that could be used in a sentence like ***I know** why you are here* (I know ***something*** - that something being *the reason that you are here*).

Comment: Possibly. But how does that help you? You don't seem to have grasped the fact that *sentences in English require subject/verb inversion*, which is far more useful that knowing whether some sequence of words counts as a "clause" or not.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. In my way of looking at things, “why you are here” is a ***noun phrase***. In which context, "phrase" simply means it's *a noun consisting of more than one word*. But all definitions I know of for a "clause" require that it should include a ***verb*** (phrase) as well as a noun (phrase).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132091/discussion-between-user284747-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a question, you have to [invert](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/question-forms) the subject and the auxiliary verb/be-verb. Watch what happens to the words **you** and **are** in the following two sentences:

> You are ready. - *statement*
> Are you ready? - *question*

Looking at your sentence, there is no inversion, so it's completely unambiguous as a statement.

> I said why logic and English are inseparable.

If you want to make it a question, you would have to do inversion and put the question in quotes:

> I said "Why are logic and English inseparable?"

Alternatively, you can change the verb to indicate that it is a question:

> I asked why logic and English are inseparable.

Note that logic is uncountable, so you do not make it plural.